# Add views dynamically in ScrollView without ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an android app.There is an activity that shows application settings and user profile.So I create xml file like this.

```
   <RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView>
             <LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout>
                         //Layout for user profile
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView>
                        //for application setting
                    </ListView>

             </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

But ,as I read, nested ListView inside ScrollView is not good. "User Profile layout" is different from "Setting Layout". And there are many items inside "Setting ListView".So I must scroll both "profile layout" and "Settings " in order to get the bottom. I want to add settings(string and icon) programmatically. Are there some ways to achieve this? 
Sorry for my bad English writing skill.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is RecyclerView adapter with different view holders for profile layout and settings layout.
For your reference [enter link description here](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example)
You have to create/bind profile layout for position 0 and application setting layout for all the other positions in the RecyclerView Adapter.